# Can't "git push". "Heroku Git error" for 4 days now

Tags: git, heroku

As described in the title, I can't push to one of my apps. 
"git push" to other apps work fine, so credentials/keys set up is OK.

The error message:

```
$ git push app-remote

 !  Heroku Git error, please try again shortly.
 !  See http://status.heroku.com for current Heroku platform status.
 !  If the problem persists, please contact http://support.heroku.com.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I'm disappointed with Heroku support, as my ticket have no answer after 4 days :(

Comment: Some thoughts that might help you... Are you positive your permissions are correct? Are you able to interact with the application in other ways? does heroku apps:info show your app? Did you change the name recently?

Comment: I'm pretty sure my permissions are correct. Push worked for this app last friday, then stopped working.

Comment: `heroku apps:info` works. Everything but git access seems to be working fine.

Comment: Me too. I was pushing every day for months, and it was fine. Now I can't push. Tried `gem update heroku` but that didn't help. Can push to another heroku app just fine. Guess I'll try rebooting (Mac).

Comment: After 4 days they have answered my ticket. They said there's a problem with the app git repo and they will have to reset it. I've authorized the reset a few minutes after their response but they still didn't do it. It's been 6 days now, and I'm very disappointed with Heroku's support.

Comment: can you push a different branch? what does heroku logs --tail say?

Comment: I've had this problem as well across multiple repos. Happens intermittently. They've also reset one of our repositories but it didn't resolve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository was corrupt.

The Heroku support took over a week to fix it.

Comment: First time I ever heard of a corrupted git repository. Glad they helped you out

Answer (score 11):

`$ git push heroku master`

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '50.19.85.156' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

heroku keys:add fixed this for me

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue out of nowhere as well. Simply restarting the dynos with `heroku restart` fixed it for me. I'm guessing for the reasons mentioned by @akegalj

Answer (score 4):

I was getting similar response:

```
$ git push heroku master
exec request failed on channel 0
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

After **visiting application URL** push went ok. I suppose error has to do something with Heorku idling applications which are not used in past hour (mine was on free/dev account).

Comment: visiting application URL fixed it for me, it was probably hybernated

Comment: This is also the issue I had. Not good when I want my CI to 'just work'.