# git push heroku master fails in heroku

Tags: windows, heroku

I am starting out with heroku and am following the getting to start with heroku tutorial. I am on windows 7 and am using Windows powershell as the command line.

The commands that I am using are

```
git clone git://github.com/heroku/ruby-sample.git
cd ruby-sample
heroku login
heroku create
git push heroku master
heroku open
```

The directory was cloned and after `heroku login` I got `Authentication successful.` in the command line. After `heroku create` I got

```
Creating immense-lowlands-8694... done, stack is cedar
http://immense-lowlands-8694.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:immense-lowlands-8694.git
Git remote heroku added
```

so the app was added to my heroku account. But **there was problem with `git push heroku master`**. I got

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**What I have tried so far**

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006629/git-push-heroku-master-getting-following-error) said about adding keys but it is for Linux and didn't work for Windows 7.
- I used `heroku keys` and it says that there is a key present for my e-mail ID.
- As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15591754/2235567) says I tried `heroku keys:add` and got

this

```
Found existing public key: C:/Users/Aseem/.ssh/github_rsa.pub
Uploading SSH public key C:/Users/Aseem/.ssh/github_rsa.pub... done
```

but after that the error didn't end.

- I tried what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000662/git-heroku-permission-denied-public-key-after-adding-public-key) says but `ssh-keygen` wasn't recognized so I guess it's for linux.
- I tried removing using `heroku keys:remove KEY_NAME` and then `heroku login` to login again but that didn't take care of the error either.

What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Create a new key using `ssh-keygen` this answer would help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000662/git-heroku-permission-denied-public-key-after-adding-public-key

Comment: @uDaY Do I need to install `ssh-keygen` separately? I had trued that but it wasn't recognized in windows powershell.

Comment: you can use the existing github keys but I wouldnt recommend. Try to create a new set of keys for heroku. ssh-keygen comes with MSysGit package in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed `MSysGit` instead of `git`. Added the `C:\Program Files(x86)\Git\bin` directory to the PATH variable and then doing what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15115156/2235567) says solved the problem.

Comment: Heroku toolbelt on windows leaves a fair bit to be desired it seems.